# How to Add Coffeescript to Node.js Skeleton Framework?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, coffeescript, gulp

Skeleton (https://github.com/dstroot/skeleton) seems to be a very solid "framework" for node.js, and has all the middleware that I am looking for except coffee script. How can I possibly add it to my project?

I set up a gulp.task in gulpfile.js which is looking for the coffee scripts to compile into javascript but where do these compiled files go? And how will they be used after they are compiled into *.js?

```
gulp.task('coffee', function ()
```

Initially I will have both javascript and coffee.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well since all the `.js` files are in the `controller` folder (except the test ones), you could create a gulp `coffee` task which could be something like this :

```
gulp.task('coffee', function () {
  return gulp.src('./controllers/*.coffee')
    .pipe(coffee())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./controllers/'));
}):
```

Your `coffee` files will be in the same folder as the `js` one, but you can change that as you prefer.

You will have to change the `scripts` task a bit to add the `coffee` as dependency :

```
gulp.task('scripts', ['coffee'], function () {
```

Also remove the `js` watcher to replace it by the `coffee`.